# Modelling real life process - threads and concurrency

Tags: objective-c, modeling

I dont even know if this is possible but I would like to model a real life process in that a number of people process a number of samples.

Say I have 100 samples and 5 people are available to process these samples where each of them can process at a rate of 20 per hour.

I have the following code for a processor class which allocates samples to processing objects if they are free to do processing.

The 1st 5 get allocated no problem, but then I seem to go into an infinite loop in that the processors never seem to set themselves to 'free' after the timer has elapsed. Any suggestions as to why this is occurring or a better approach. The aim would be to be able to model a process by having different rates and numbers of processors.

```
-(id)init {
    if(![super init])
        return nil;
    self.free = YES;
    self.bookingInRate = 20;
    return self;
}

-(void)bookingIn:(NSInteger *)sampleNumber {
    self.free = NO;
    NSNumber *timeToBookIn = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:((60/self.bookingInRate) * 60)/1000];

    NSLog(@"Booking in sample number: %ld", sampleNumber);
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1;
    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: interval];
    NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                                   interval: interval
                                   target: self
                                   selector:@selector(onTick:sampleNumber:)
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
 }

 -(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer sampleNumber:(NSInteger *)sampleNumber {
     NSLog(@"Booked in sample no: %ld", sampleNumber);
     self.free = YES;
 }
```

I then run a modelling loop using:

```
NSMutableArray *sampleNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    [sampleNumbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}

NSMutableArray *bookerIns = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    [bookerIns addObject:[[HEFTBookerIn alloc]init]];
}


int i = 0;
long countSamples;

countSamples = [sampleNumbers count];

// loop sample numbers

while ([sampleNumbers count] != 0 )
{
    NSInteger sampleNo = [[sampleNumbers objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    long count = [bookerIns count];
    int counter = 0;

    //loop over booker ins

    int j;

    for (j=0; j <count ; j++) {
        HEFTBookerIn *booker = [bookerIns objectAtIndex:counter];
        if (booker.free == YES){
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                [booker bookingIn:sampleNo];
            });

            NSLog(@"Booking in : %ld", sampleNo);
            [booker bookingIn:sampleNo];
            [sampleNumbers removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            //i ++;
            break;
        } else {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok,and what is your question?

Comment: Why don't the processing objects appear to reset their status to free? Supplementary question is would this be better implemented using multiple threads and messaging to indicate a processor object is free to take next sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that sticks out is that you are passing a selector that's invalid in your call to `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> *aSelector*
>
> The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must
>   have the following signature:
>
> `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer`
>
> The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

So the data you expect in this method is not getting passed back to it, if it's getting called at all. Try using a timer with an invocation instead of a target/action, or use `dispatch_after()` (I'd consider the latter to be more straightforward).

Comment: Needed 

if (booker.free == YES){
                dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
                [booker bookingIn:sampleNo];
                [sampleNumbers removeObjectAtIndex:i];

As well